# Create and open folder modify path

Tags: excel, vba, directory, path

I use the code below to create and open a folder from excel when I press a button but I want the created folder to be in the same location like the excel workbook. Can you please help me modif the code? Thank you!

```
Sub btn1_click()
Dim dir As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
dir = ActiveCell.value
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
If Not fso.folderexists(dir) Then
    fso.createfolder (dir)
End If
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & dir, vbNormalFocus)
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: If the `ActiveWorkbook` has not been saved yyet, it will not have a path. How would you handle that case?

Comment: Hello, I use the vba code for an excel gantt chart that is located in specific folder and will always be saved. I want that the folder that i create from the excel to have the same path like the excel workbook. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `fso.createfolder path & dir` ? It depends on what you have in the active cell, and you did not include that information. Try using `MsgBox path & dir` to debug it and figure out what you need to get the path you want. Another thing, naming your variable `dir` is a bad idea, it that is also the name of a VBA function, and that can create conflicts if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create and Explore a Subfolder Using the Active Cell's Value

- The code is written for any active cell so be a little careful how you use it to not end up with folders in the wrong places.
- If you run it by using a button, you are ensuring that it will use the right cell since the active sheet is the one containing the button and containing the active cell.

```vb
Sub CreateActiveCellSubFolder()
    
    Const ExploreIfSubFolderExists As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet ' it could be a chart
    
    If ash Is Nothing Then ' no active sheet
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If ash.Type <> xlWorksheet Then
        MsgBox "The active sheet '" & ash.Name & "' is not a worksheet.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ash.Parent
    
    If Len(wb.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The workbook '" & wb.Name & "' containing the active sheet '" _
            & ash.Name & "' has not been saved yet.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the active sheet is a worksheet, it has an active cell at any time,
    ' no matter what is selected.
    Dim aCell As Range: Set aCell = ActiveCell
    
    Dim SubFolderName As String: SubFolderName = CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
    
    If Len(SubFolderName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The cell '" & aCell.Address(0, 0) & "' is blank.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SubFolderPath As String
    SubFolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & SubFolderName
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If fso.FolderExists(SubFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & SubFolderName & "' already exists.", _
            vbInformation
        If Not ExploreIfSubFolderExists Then Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim ErrNum As Long
        On Error Resume Next
            fso.CreateFolder SubFolderPath
            ErrNum = Err.Number
'            If ErrNum > 0 Then
'                Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " _
'                    & Err.Description
'            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNum = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Created the folder '" & SubFolderName & "'.", _
                vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not create the folder '" & SubFolderName & "'.", _
                vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    wb.FollowHyperlink SubFolderPath
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is working perfect on local directory, but when i copy it on one drive for desktop I get an error message. Is there a workaround for onedrive folders?

Comment: Error message: Could not create the folder " folder_name"